# How to embed array in new Function construct

Tags: javascript

How can I get javascript array in a function which I create like this:
[image]

Thanks.

**Edit:**
Thanks for taking care about eval, evil etc. but my question actually is not about pros and cons of eval. Thanks.

**Edit2:**
Thanks Saml. Your answer pushed my to the right direction:
[image]

**P.S.**
Programming idioms sometimes becomes religion. Anyway I've got what I needed. Happy coding.

Comment: Don't create functions like that. If you've got a good enough reason to disagree with my first statement, then you'd know how to reference an array from `Function`'s arguments.

Comment: Are you trying to log an array containing the values of `a`, `b`, and `c`?

Comment: What is this code *trying* to do? Have an example use-case? I would generally think `f = (function () { var ar = arguments; return function () { console.log.apply(this, ar) } })(a,b,c)` would be sufficient .. (in early versions of FF this would break as apply required an Array, that is fixed now)

Comment: @zzzzBov Thanks for warning. Actually I now of eval etc. Anyway I am still interested.

Comment: @Saulius "eval" is *just as broken* (without a *very specific* and *somewhat questionable* use-case).

Comment: @Saulius, don't use `eval` either.

Comment: @RyanLynch No it's just an example. I want to get array in a log.

Comment: @zzzzBov Just for the record when you need to pass function and you can control arguments it gets sometimes it is useful. I am not denying that it is better to avoid. But at some circumstances I don't think it is absolute evil. It's not a religion anyway.

Comment: @Saulius, I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to describe, but I'm certain that `eval` is not needed for it.

Comment: @zzzzBov Is it possible "to be certain" of ways to resolve when you are not sure about understanding the problem? :-)
I won't go into details (as it won't fit to comment) but here is some explanation for example http://phrogz.net/JS/classes/CreatingAnonymousFunctions.html

Comment: @Saulius, few of the examples in that post were well written, there are better approaches. Please send me an email describing the details of where you believe `eval` or `new Function` are appropriate, I'm genuinely interested in learning if you've found some use cases that I wasn't aware of.

Comment: @zzzBov ok. I'll do but a bit latter.

Comment: @zzzzBov Not sure how to contact you. Here is the link: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1Anfj-kBBt6sc0uU0DJ84TUMaDmIVu22DZ-IC3gtgGSc/edit Let me know if you have better ideas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make sure that whatever body gets passed to the constructor is a string, so if myArray is your array, use

```
'['+myArray.join(',')+']'
```

Or in your case,

```
var fBody = 'console.log(['+myArray.join(',')+']);';
var b = new Function(fBody);
```

Comment: You can also always use JSON.stringify() to convert a Javascript object to a string representation.

Comment: JSON.stringify() will do it even better. Thanks.